# Showing all results even using GROUP BY CLAUSE

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

Query :
How to sort by months ?

```
select format(datee,'mmm-yyyy') as [Months],sum(amount) as Amount 
from ledger_broker 
where ref_from like 'Purchase' 
group by format(datee,'mmm-yyyy') 
order by format(datee,'mmm-yyyy') desc
```

Output : 
[image]

Comment: So what is the question? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping by the same exact column which you select:

```
SELECT t.[Months], t.Amount
FROM
(
    SELECT MONTH(datee) AS theMonth, YEAR(datee) AS theYear,
        FORMAT(datee,'mmm-yyyy') AS [Months], SUM(amount) AS Amount
    FROM ledger_transporter
    WHERE ref_from LIKE 'Purchase'
    GROUP BY MONTH(datee), YEAR(datee), FORMAT(datee, 'mmm-yyyy')
) t
ORDER BY t.theYear DESC, t.theMonth DESC
```

One way to order by date is to select the numeric month and year in your query.

Comment: Biegelesien : how can i sort months in descending order 

i used 'order by format(Add_Date,'mmm-yyyy') desc' , but its showing May-2016,Jan-2016 etc

Comment: @DineshSolanki I updated my answer per your requirements.  Please mark correct if it solved your question.

Comment: Wait...what database are you using?  Please update your question.

Comment: VB6 with MS-ACCESS DATABASE

Comment: @DineshSolanki I updated my answer again.  This should work with the caveat that there will be extra columns being selected.

Comment: Still the same output in months column :(

Comment: I doubt this.  What is the output now?

Answer (score 0):

change `group by datee` to `group by format(datee,'mmm-yyyy')`.

```
select distinct format(datee,'mmm-yyyy') as [Months], sum(amount) as Amount
from ledger_transporter
where ref_from like 'Purchase'
group by format(datee,'mmm-yyyy')
order by Month(datee)
```

The reason is that your date, which I assume is say 01-FEB-2016 and 02-FEB-2016, is different and if you group by it, you will get 2 different records for it. 
However, for `format(datee,'mmm-yyyy')`, ie `FEB-2016`, both of these dates are same. Hence the mismatch

Comment: If it worked, then please accept the answer by clicking on tick symbol on left of the answer, so it could be closed. Thanks.

Comment: i used 'order by format(Add_Date,'mmm-yyyy') desc' to sort but its not helping